# openfire 3.7.1 works great, but dies on restart (Kraken plugin installed)

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I have installed openfire 3.7.1 and uploaded Kraken plugin (IM Gateway). It worked fine. But on restarting the system. Its dying every time. I have tried re-installing also.
A part of the error is mentioned below. Can anyone tell what is the issue?

Is Kraken not compatible with openfire 3.7.1?

Error: log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [net.sf.kraken.util.Log4JToOpenfireAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.kraken.util.Log4JToOpenfireAppender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(NativeMethod)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:179)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:320)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:121)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:664)
    at ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.. it seems kraken 1.1.2 is causing this problem with openfire 3.7.1. Tried kraken 1.1.3 beta, and it  is working fine